Topology of uniform convergence on topological modules as right adjoint
Let $I$ be a set, $\mathrm{Mod}$ be the category of modules and consider the adjunction  $(-)^{\oplus I}:\mathrm{Mod}\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Mod}:(-)^{\times I}$, where $X^{\oplus I}=\bigoplus_{i\in I}X$ is the direct sum and $X^{\times I}=\prod_{i\in I}X$ is the product of modules.
When $X$ is a topological module, endow $X^{\times I}$ with the topology of uniform convergence, so that $U^{\times I}$ is a neighbourhood base of $0$ in $X^{\times I}$ as $U$ runs over a neighbourhood base of $0$ in $X$.
A direct computation, shows that the functor $(-)^{\times I}:\mathrm{TopMod}\to\mathrm{TopMod}$ preserves initial sources.
By tauth lift theorem, we have a morphism of adjunctions:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\mathrm{TopMod}@>>>\mathrm{TopMod}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathrm{Mod}@>>(-)^{\oplus I}>\mathrm{Mod}
\end{CD}\begin{CD}
\mathrm{TopMod}@<<<\mathrm{TopMod}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathrm{Mod}@<<(-)^{\times I}<\mathrm{Mod}
\end{CD}$$

Question. There exists an explicit description of the topology on
$X^{\oplus I}$ when $X$ is a topological module? There exists a name
for this topology?

